# MainActivityBinding file not being generated in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, data-binding, android-databinding

I am trying to get databinding functionality implemented in code. 
In build.gradle I am adding databinding.enabled=true
but it is giving error cannot resolve symbol enabled. How can this be corrected?

Comment: DId you tried the file name *ActivityMainBinding* ??

Comment: it worked with Activity Main Binding ... Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Well for the data binding enabled projects the Binding classes will be auto generated with name as **LayoutNameBinding**

But for most of the case the binding name for **MainActivity** will generated with same name creation logic, ie **ActivityMainBinding** since the layout name be `activity_main.xml`

ie the Layout name. eg if the layout name is *custom_layout.xml*, then the binding class name will be *CustomLayoutBinding*

Happy coding.. :)

Comment: Save my time. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

The best way to fix this problem is:
Go to **Gradle.Build (Madulus)** and below the **buildTypes**, type the following code and **sync the project**.

```
viewBinding{
    enabled = true
}
```

also you must add this plugin in the gradle plugin:

```
    plugins {
        id 'com.android.application'
        id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
        id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
   }
```

Now if you write the id of your widget you will get it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Wrap a nascent activity_main.xml in `<data> </data>`
2. add to your program the following line

   private lateinit var ActivityMainBinding: ViewDataBinding
3. recompile